# Debugger comes up after malware cleanup

Tags: virus, malware

I had some nasty malware on my computer yesterday.

The malware mimicked a windows security alert. Any time an executable tried to start, the malware would shut the new process down and pop up a little tooltip saying it was harmful. I couldn't even bring up task manager in non-safe-mode.

I was able to remove the malware using MalwareBytes and am now able to run processes.

However, it seems that any time I launch something, and possibly at random times, the Visual Studio Debugger comes up pops up with the unhandled exception:

**`"Object doesn't support this property or method"`**

The exception originates from different executables (most frequently **svchost.exe**).

Is this a residual effect from the malware, or is the malware still installed? How can I fix it so that it's not still trying to run the quarantined code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think installing internet explorer 8 fixed this. Don't ask me why I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the virus infected some dll that other apps needed - IE 8 installed a new version.

Using sfc /scannow would likely fix the issue by checking system files against what's on the installer cd.